# Removing a string of letters from a String Java

Tags: java, string

Okay been on this for a while now and have gone through many different versions of doing this the goal is to have a method like remove("pdi") and it will return "eter er cke"

The `remove()` function has to remove all the characters in myString matching with characters of `args` passed as an argument to the function.

```
public class CodioCustomString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(remove("pdi"));
    
}

//2 Variables
static String myString = "peter piper picked";
boolean isSet;

//constructor

public static String remove(String arg) {
    char[] chars = arg.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(myString);
    for(char i: chars) {
        for(int k = 0; k < myString.length(); k++) {
            if(i == myString.charAt(k)) {
                newString.deleteCharAt(k);
                continue;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }

        }
        
        }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Comment: After the first delete in StringBuilder, it’s not consistent with myString.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three methods to do it. The methods take two argument.

- the `target` string subject to removal
- the `source` string of characters to be removed.

```
String result1 = remove1("peter piper picked", "pbi");
System.out.println(result1);

String result2 = remove2("peter piper picked", "pbi");
System.out.println(result2);

String result3 = remove3("peter piper picked", "pbi");
System.out.println(result3);
```

prints

```
eter er cked
eter er cked
eter er cked
```

**Explanations**

**remove1**

The easiest way is as follows:

- use `replaceAll` which takes a regular expression
- `[abc]` is a character class which matches any of those characters. So simply create one by surrounding your letters to be removed with brackets.
- replace the occurrence of those characters with an empty string.

```
public static String remove1(String target, String toBeRemoved) {
    return target.replaceAll("[" + toBeRemoved + "]", "");
}
```

**remove2**

If you prefer to do it in a loop you can do the following:

- simply iterate across the characters of the string.
- if the removal letters contains the character, ignore it.
- else append it to a `StringBuilder`

```
public static String remove2(String target, String toBeRemoved) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : target.toCharArray()) {
        if (!toBeRemoved.contains(Character.toString(ch))) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**remove3**

This method streams the characters.

- map each character to a string
- filter out the ones to be removed
- collect into a new String using `Collectors.joining()`

```
public static String remove3(String target, String toBeRemoved) {
    return target.chars().mapToObj(Character::toString)
            .filter(Predicate.not(toBeRemoved::contains)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: I used the remove2. How would I get it to ignore numbers and symbols for example  remove2 (I see 10 dogs!, 1!e) would return "I s 10 dogs!"

Comment: Could I add an if else and use isDigit() in some way? or would that only work for numbers and not symbols?

Comment: Yes. You could add `&& !Character.isDigit(ch)` to the condition. You could also just alter the list from `pbi` to `pbi0123456789`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing the length of myString in the for loop which is fixed. Instead you should be comparing it with the length of StringBuilder ( newString in this case) as you are reducing the length when performing the delete operation.

Also, the time complexity (t.c) of the above code is O(n*k) where n is the length of the string and k the length of string that needs to be removed.

You can improve the time complexity by storing the character in a set and then iterating the newString and performing the remove operation.

```
public class CodioCustomString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remove("pdi"));
        System.out.println(remove2("pdi"));
    }

    // 2 Variables
    static String myString = "peter piper picked";
    boolean isSet;

    /** tc - o(nk) where k is length of args string and n is length of string */
    private static String remove(String arg) {
        char[] chars = arg.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(myString);
        for (char i : chars) {
            for (int k = 0; k < newString.length(); k++) {
                if (i == newString.charAt(k)) {
                    newString.deleteCharAt(k);
                    k--;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }
        return newString.toString();
    }

    /**
     * tc - o(n) + o(k) where k is length of args string and n is length of string
     */
    private static String remove2(String arg) {
        char[] chars = arg.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (char i : chars) {
            set.add(i);
        }
        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(myString);

        for (int k = 0; k < newString.length(); k++) {
            if (set.contains(newString.charAt(k))) { // set.contains is o(1) operations
                newString.deleteCharAt(k);
                k--;
            }

        }

        return newString.toString();
    }
}
```

and the expected output :

```
eter er cke
eter er cke
```